# Undestanding antenna gain applicability

Tags: signal-power, radio, channel

While searching for the info about antenna gain and why it is GAIN I found this interesting example:

*If the two antennas in the drawing are “welded” together, how much power will be measured at point
A? (Line loss L = L = 0.5, and 10log L or L = 3 dB)*

[image]

The answer is:
***Since there are no active components, you cannot
end up with more power than you started with**. The correct answer is
10 dBm - 3 dB - small loss -3 dB = 4 dBm - small loss*

But then additional comment is given:
*If the antennas were separated by 5 ft and were in the far field, the antenna gain could be used with space loss formulas to calculate (at 5 GHz): 10 dBm - 3 dB + 6 dB - 50 dB (space loss) + 6 dB -3 dB = -34 dBm*

Well, now antennas gains are taken into consideration. I wonder what if space loss would be 5 dB instead of 50, then it turns out:
10 dBm - 3 dB + 6 dB - 10 dB (space loss) + 6 dB -3 dB = 11 dBm, i.e. more power then started with.

Apparently it is not possible, right?
The requirement of a "far field" always assumes that
tx antenna gain + rx antenna_gain < space loss

is my understanding correct?

Comment: if you find one of these answers helpful, would you mind marking it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, the gain of an antenna is not like that of an op-amp. It is just a measure of how sharply it focuses the beam in a specific direction with regards to a reference antenna, e.g., an isotropic antenna which is generally used for this comparison. The higher the gain of an antenna, the higher portion of the total radiated power is directed in the direction of concern. Although this explanation is not relevant to the actual question, I presume that it is good to keep that simple perspective in mind.

So, as to the question; reducing the path loss of 50 dB from 5 dB literally means, if the ambient exhibits the same properties, approaching the antenna pair to each other. After some extent, however, Friis's path loss formula doesn't apply anymore, i.e., it starts to produce illogical results. According to the formula below;

$$L_{FS} = 20\log\left(\frac{4\pi{d}}{\lambda}\right)\ \mbox{ dB}$$

in order to make the path loss an attenuating effect, the following relationship must be satisfied:

$$d > \frac{\lambda}{4\pi}$$

Beyond that distance, the transmission equation starts to produce the expected results.

Answer (score 4):

The answer has to do with the definitions of antenna gain and space loss. Antenna "gain" is essentially defined *relative* to space loss, which is due to isotropic (uniform spherical) propagation. It is unlike the gain due to an amplifier, which actually adds power to the signal.

Before we go too far, antenna gain and directivity are often used interchangeably. The difference is that gain takes into account losses in the antenna hardware such as VSWR loss. With this caveat, I will use them interchangeably from here on.

### Antenna Directivity

Antenna directivity is defined as the ratio of the area of an isotropic beam to the area covered by the actual beam. In other words, if the antenna had no directivity, i.e, all power is radiated equally in all directions (spherical radiation), it would have a directivity of 1 (0 dBi). When the antenna has a non-isotropic pattern such that most of the power is concentrated in a small area (such as a pencil beam), its directivity is greater than 0 dBi (6 dBi in your example). The units "dBi" hint at this, meaning "dB relative to isotropic."

From this definition, it should be clear that no power is actually added by the antenna, only concentrated in a certain direction. The "gain" is *relative* to an isotropic antenna.

### Space Loss

One way space loss is defined as $1/(4\pi R^2)$. This is because electromagnetic waves spread equally in all directions (like ripples in a pond). Thus, power is spread over the area of a sphere of radius $R$, which is $4\pi R^2$. Two way space loss would be $(4\pi )^2R^4$.

### Putting it all Together

The relative definitions of gain and space loss are the reason antenna directivity is taken into account when power is transmitted over the air. If there were no directivity (0 dBi antenna), power density would decrease due to space loss at a rate of $1/(4\pi R^2)$. The gain ($G$) of the antenna relative to isotropic radiation compensates for this by concentrating the power in a certain direction, reducing the space loss by a factor of $G = 4\pi A\eta\ /\lambda^2$ (see comment below for a derivation of this equation). Thus, the received power (for one way over the air transmission) is $P_{Tx} + G_{Tx} - space\ loss\ + G_{Rx}$. **If there is no space loss (i.e., the antennas are "welded together"), antenna directivity ceases to have meaning as it is really only defined relative to space loss.**

Comment: Equation for Antenna Gain: 
If you use the common rule of thumb that 3 dB beamwidth in radians is given by $\lambda/D$, where $\lambda$ is wavelength and $D$ is the size of the antenna in the dimension of interest, you can work out that the area covered by the beam is roughly $R\lambda/D_{az} \centerdot R\lambda/D_{el} =  R^2\lambda^2/A$, where $A$ is the area of the antenna. The gain (taking into account antenna efficiency, $\eta$, as well) is then: 
$$ 
G = \frac{4\pi R^2}{R^2\lambda^2/(A\eta)} = \frac{4\pi A\eta}{\lambda^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems that one runs in to when dealing with Decibels (dB). Decibels are a ratio to something else. When dealing with dB, it's very important to establish what the dB is being defined in reference to. If dB's are referenced to different things, you cannot generally add them together.

In this exercise, looking into what the difference between dBm is versus what dBi is should have led you into digging deeper on how to apply them.

This problem is attempting to exploit the fact that one will blindly apply the dBi gain value as they would a dB or dBm, without first checking the real meaning of dBi. Now that we're here, let's do that.

### Isotropic Radiator and Power Density

The theory applied here is all based around the *isotropic radiator*. This fictitious device radiates some power $P_t$ (transmitted power) uniformly across the area of a sphere, which is $4\pi R^2$. This means that the meaningful power to be captured is actually a power surface density having units of $W/m^2$.

The entire objective of a receiving antenna is to be able to capture as much of this density as possible using it's effective area, yielding a direct power in Watts to be absorbed at the terminals of the antenna.

At a given distance $R$ from the isotropic radiator, the power density $S $ is

$$S = \frac{P_t}{4\pi R^2} \space \frac{W}{m^2}$$

As the distance $R$ increases, the sphere is now larger, and thus the power density decreases. Thus, the factor $1/(4\pi R^2)$ establishes the *space loss* when considering one-way travel. When considering a receiver, the wavelength $\lambda$ can be introduced as part of space loss to account for the effective aperture of the receiving antenna, but we won't go into that here.

### Antenna Gain

*Antenna Gain* is how much better an antenna directs power **relative to** an isotropic radiator. Gain in general is a function of angles, usually described by a spherical coordinate system. Let' assume a spherical coordinate system with azimuth angle $\theta$ and elevation angle $\phi$.

When an antenna is designed, there is a desired set of angles were want to radiate as much power as we can that was fed into the antenna. For the isotropic radiator, it's *gain pattern* is unity for all angles:

$$G(\theta,\phi) = 1$$

This factor of 1 is implicitly in the power density formula above. Having said that, the power density is also a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Now let's consider some other antenna we have designed. For a particular set of angles, this antenna focuses more power in that direction, and less so in others. The antenna achieves some gain **relative to** the isotropic radiator given the same input power $P_t$, and we give this the Decibel unit of dBi.

So now for this antenna, we can describe its effect on the radiated power density as

$$S(\theta,\phi) = \frac{P_tG(\theta,\phi)}{4\pi R^2} \space \frac{W}{m^2}$$

For the angles were the antenna focuses power some factor better than the isotropic radiator, the gain (in dBi) is positive. Likewise it's negative for where it focuses less, and **zero** for where it focuses just like the isotropic radiator.

The takeaway is that despite being a "gain", the total amount of power has not increased or decreased. The gain is achieved by how the power is directed in a particular direction.

In your problem where the antennas are welded together, the dBi gain no longer applies, because they are no longer acting as antennas, which provide the gain by how well they focus power in a particular direction, not by amplifying power directly.

Comment: Your statement _the difference between dBm is versus what dBi_ made me think about how they calculate channel budget. It is always like: Ptx(dB**m**) + Gtx(dB**i**) - Path_loss (dB) + Grx(dB**i**). I mean they sum up dBm and dBi and get correct results.

Comment: @Vaims There's nothing stopping you from applying the logarithms once the relationship is established. The equation works because it has been formulated in that all of the relationships in how gain is defined has a physical meaning. The exercise in your problem was to identify this when it comes to antenna gain, and that it does *not* apply as shown in the diagram.